# Heatmap with xts

Tags: r, xts, heatmap

Hi all I want to plot a heatmap:

df ist {xts} and looking like this:

```
structure(c(1.3728813559322, 0.871666666666667, 0.586666666666667, 
0.34, -0.31, -0.973333333333333, -1.52666666666667, -1.71333333333333, 
-0.396666666666667, 0.698333333333333, 2.84666666666667, 4.68333333333333, 
5.33833333333333, 5.66666666666667, 5.63666666666667, 5.69, 5.69666666666667, 
5.54333333333333, 5.50833333333333, 4.335, 3.065, 2.42666666666667, 
1.88666666666667, 1.47833333333333), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "", class = c("xts", 
"zoo"), index = c(1364770740, 1364774340, 1364777940, 1364781540, 
1364785140, 1364788740, 1364792340, 1364795940, 1364799540, 1364803140, 
1364806740, 1364810340, 1364813940, 1364817540, 1364821140, 1364824740, 
1364828340, 1364831940, 1364835540, 1364839140, 1364842740, 1364846340, 
1364849940, 1364853540), .Dim = c(24L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(
NULL, "df.xts"))
```

As in the following post I want to have y-axis 24 hours - one value per hour, and y-axis the date.
Is it possible to work with the existing xts format?

[ggplot2 heatmap to assign colors to breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16201221/ggplot2-heatmap-to-assign-colors-to-breaks)

I also found another example with heatmap.plus().

```
z = matrix(rnorm(30),nrow=5,ncol=6);
rlab = matrix(as.character(c(1:5,2:6,3:7,4:8)),nrow=5,ncol=4);
clab = matrix(as.character(c(1:6,6:1)),nrow=6,ncol=2);
colnames(rlab) = LETTERS[1:dim(rlab)[2]];
colnames(clab) = 1:dim(clab)[2];
heatmap.plus(z,ColSideColors=clab,RowSideColors=rlab);
```

Example is running, but I would prefer a legend, and my data look different from df - and not an xts with date.
Thanks!

Comment: Use `dput` to transmit a reproducible example. That does not "look" like a properly constructed xts-object but we have no way of knowing if you only show the console output.

Comment: Thanks DWin, never got before what you mean with dput - sorry. I edited! Thank you!

Comment: Your ``dput` object has an additional attribute: 'tclass' when compared to `dput(sample.xts)`-object in the help page for ?xts. That seems to be affecting the way the print method is working with the POSIXct index. It prints as though it is "numeric" (with output in seconds rather than looking like a date). If I remove that 'tclass' value from the structure call, it then prints normally because it also has a regular `class=c("xts", "zoo")`. I'm using `zoo_1.7-9` and `xts_0.9-3`.

Comment: Would you please be so kind to make an example with the data? I don't know how to deal with it: I need the tclass with asPOSIXct to subset and to get the hourly mean.

Comment: You should show how you created the object and how you want to use it. (And I can see no reason to add a `tclass` of the same composition as the existing `.indexCLASS`.) When I attempt to add a `tclass` to an existing xts-object with the same value as an existing `.indexCLASS`, there is no addition of a `tclass` attribute

Comment: I am getting normal data as mentioned before: date, value. I am doing `read.csv()` and then setting  `df$time<-as.POSIXct(df$time,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")` and last step ist to convert and make to index: `df.zoo<-zoo(df[,-1],df[,1])` and `df.xts<-as.xts(df.zoo)`. Thanks

Comment: I fail to understand the phrase "normal data". Furthermore `heatmap.plus` is not from xts or ggplot2, so where is it from?

Comment: 'heatmap.plus' is an own package!

Answer (score 0):

This perhaps isn't an answer to the heatmap question, but this code and output will not display properly in a comment. (Noting my comments above...) Using an object named `dat`created from the `dput` output above, but with the tclass-attribute removed, I subsetted it and:

```
dput(dat['2013-04-01'])
structure(c(0.698333333333333, 2.84666666666667, 4.68333333333333, 
5.33833333333333, 5.66666666666667, 5.63666666666667, 5.69, 5.69666666666667, 
5.54333333333333, 5.50833333333333, 4.335, 3.065, 2.42666666666667, 
1.88666666666667, 1.47833333333333), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "", tzone = "", class = c("xts", "zoo"), index = c(1364803140, 
1364806740, 1364810340, 1364813940, 1364817540, 1364821140, 1364824740, 
1364828340, 1364831940, 1364835540, 1364839140, 1364842740, 1364846340, 
1364849940, 1364853540), .Dim = c(15L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, "df.xts"))
> d2 <- dat['2013-04-01']
> tclass(d2) <- "POSIXct"
> d2   #displays with time appropriate format
                       df.xts
2013-04-01 00:59:00 0.6983333
2013-04-01 01:59:00 2.8466667
2013-04-01 02:59:00 4.6833333
2013-04-01 03:59:00 5.3383333
2013-04-01 04:59:00 5.6666667
2013-04-01 05:59:00 5.6366667
2013-04-01 06:59:00 5.6900000
2013-04-01 07:59:00 5.6966667
2013-04-01 08:59:00 5.5433333
2013-04-01 09:59:00 5.5083333
2013-04-01 10:59:00 4.3350000
2013-04-01 11:59:00 3.0650000
2013-04-01 12:59:00 2.4266667
2013-04-01 13:59:00 1.8866667
2013-04-01 14:59:00 1.4783333
> dput(d2)
structure(c(0.698333333333333, 2.84666666666667, 4.68333333333333, 
5.33833333333333, 5.66666666666667, 5.63666666666667, 5.69, 5.69666666666667, 
5.54333333333333, 5.50833333333333, 4.335, 3.065, 2.42666666666667, 
1.88666666666667, 1.47833333333333), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "", tzone = "", class = c("xts", "zoo"), index = structure(c(1364803140, 
1364806740, 1364810340, 1364813940, 1364817540, 1364821140, 1364824740, 
1364828340, 1364831940, 1364835540, 1364839140, 1364842740, 1364846340, 
1364849940, 1364853540), tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), .Dim = c(15L, 
1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "df.xts"))
```

No added tclass attribute after : `tclass(d2) <- "POSIXct"`. So I wonder if the heatmap axis problem relates to an improperly formed xts object.